# nvprof with MPICH

Tags: fortran, mpi, openacc, nvprof

I am trying to profile an MPI/OpenACC Fortran code.  I found a site that details how to run nvprof with MPI [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#axzz4B0e6QtP7).  The examples given are for OpenMPI.  However, I am limited to MPICH and I can't figure out the equivalent.  Anyone know what it would be?

Comment: Could you be more specific in what isn't working for you?

Comment: The examples use a variable OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK like so: `-o output.%h.%p.%q{OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK}`  That variable is unique to OpenMPI.  I need the MPICH equivalent.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell the only OpenMPI specific parts of the `nvprof` [examples](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#mpi-nvprof) are the use of `OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK` to get a unique filename for each rank. According to the discussion [here](http://lists.mcs.anl.gov/pipermail/mpich-discuss/2012-April/012260.html) you may be able to use either `PMI_RANK` or `PMI_ID` instead.

On my system I have the following small program

```
program env
  implicit none
  call system("echo $PMI_RANK")
end program env
```

I compile with `mpif90 env.f90 -o test` and run with `mpirun -np 2 ./test` and get

```
0
1
```

as output. So I think you can just replace `-o output.%h.%p.%q{OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK}` with `-o output.%h.%p.%q{PMI_RANK}`.

For the `cray-mpt` mpi library I believe the correct variable is in fact `ALPS_APP_PE` instead.

Comment: Thanks!  Will give it a shot!

Comment: Also, `-x ENV_VAR1 -x ENV_VAR2 ...` should be replaced by `-envlist ENV_VAR1,ENV_VAR2,...`.

Comment: @HristoIliev  Sorry, you lost me.  Is this a flag in the mpi execution command?  I use aprun and it has no such flag.

Comment: @d_1999  Thanks for the suggestion, but the system doesn't recognize either PMI_RANK or PMI_ID.  Returns an error immediately.

Comment: @bob.sacamento As you've just mentioned you're using `aprun` I guess you're actually running on a Cray system which likely uses Cray's mpt mpi library which I think is related to mpich but is heavily customised. As such I've updated the answer to include what should be the correct replacement for `PMI_RANK` (tested on a Cray system in the UK).

Comment: @d_1999 Job now running.  Looks like it understands it.  ALPS_APP_PE.  It's so obvious in retrospect.  How did I miss it?  :)  Mind if I ask how you learned this?  Thanks!

Comment: @bob.sacamento, I noticed in the tutorial you've linked that they are passing certain environment variables to the MPI job. The option for Open MPI's `mpiexec` is `-x`. No idea how to do it on Cray.

Comment: @HristoIliev  Thanks for the info!